# Abstract classes C#

Tags: c#

**I have an interface**

```
using ClassAbstractFactory;
public interface IPlugin
{
    AbstractFactory GetFactory();  
}
```

**and an AbstractFactory**

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    public abstract AbstractCake CreateCake();
    public abstract AbstractBox CreateBox();
}

public abstract class AbstractCake
{

    public abstract void Interact(AbstractBox box);

}

public abstract class AbstractBox
{

}
```

**and I have .dll that inherit AbstractCake**

```
 public class ChocolateCake : AbstractCake
{

    private bool _isPacked;
    private bool _isDecorated;
    private string _nameOfCake;

    public ChocolateCake()
    {
        _isPacked = false;
        _isDecorated = false;
        _nameOfCake = "Шоколадный";
    }


   public bool IsPacked
   {
        get { return _isPacked; }
   }

    public bool IsDecorated
    {
        get { return _isDecorated; }

    }

    public string NameOfCake { get; set; }


    public override void Interact(AbstractBox box)
    {     
            _isPacked = true;       
    }


}
```

**I load dll like this:**

```
 public IPlugin LoadAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        Assembly ptrAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);

        foreach (Type item in ptrAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (!item.IsClass) continue;
            if (item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPlugin)))
            {
                return (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(item);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid DLL, Interface not found!");
    }

        List<IPlugin> list = new List<IPlugin>();
        foreach (var assemblyPath in GetPathsListToDll())
        {
            list.Add(LoadAssembly(assemblyPath));
        }
```

**How can I acess to attributes in my ChocolateCake,to use them like**

```
foreach (var str in list)
        {
            Boolean a = str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().IsPacked;
        }
```

or like this

```
string a = str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().NameOfCake;
```

or like this

```
str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().NameOfCake("Something");
```

or like this

```
str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().IsDecorated(true);
```

Comment: The "Right" way to do it is `AbstractCake` should have `IsPacked`, `IsDecorated`, and `NameOfCake` defined as abstract properties/methods in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the `AbstractFactory` has a method that returns `AbstractCake`, and `AbstractCake` itself has no properties at all. As it stands, you would need to downcast the Cake (direct, or with the `as` keyword) to a `ChocolateCake` prior to accessing any of its properties, which is really messy:

```
string a = (ChocolateCake)(str.GetFactory().CreateCake()).NameOfCake;
```

Here are some considerations:

1. Move the properties which are common to all types of cake into `AbstractCake`, e.g. `NameOfCake`, `IsPacked` and `IsDecorated`
2. Given that the `AbstractFactory` and `AbstractCake` classes do not have any implementation at all, consider changing these to interfaces instead of abstract classes, i.e. `ICakeFactory` and `ICake`. Concrete implementations will be `ChocolateCakeFactory` and `ChocolateCake` as before.
3. Consumers of the factory and the cake should now only access what is exposed on the interfaces (`ICakeFactory`, `ICake` and `IBox`), and not need to do any down casting or make any assumptions about the actual concrete type of Cake etc.

i.e.

```
public interface ICake
{
    void Interact(IBox box);
    bool IsPacked { get; }
    bool IsDecorated { get; }
    string NameOfCake { get; set; }
}

public class ChocolateCake : ICake
{
    private bool _isPacked;
    private bool _isDecorated;
    private string _nameOfCake;

    public ChocolateCake() // ctor is not on the interface and is implementation detail
    {
        _isPacked = false;
        _isDecorated = false;
        _nameOfCake = "Шоколадный";
    }       

    public void Interact(IBox box) {...}
    public bool IsPacked { get { return _isPacked; } }
    public bool IsDecorated { get { return _isDecorated; } }
    // ...
}

public interface ICakeFactory
{
    ICake CreateCake();
    IBox CreateBox();
}

public class ChocolateCakeFactory : ICakeFactory
{
    public ICake CreateCake()   {return new ChocolateCake();}
    public IBox CreateBox() {return new ChocolateCakeBox();} 
}
```

**Re : Usage**

It is highly unlikely that you would ever do this:

```
string a = str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().NameOfCake;
str.GetFactory().GetCake().CreateCake().NameOfCake = "Something"; // Prop setter
```

as this would create a new cake instance each time (and discard the instance). How about:

```
class Bakery
{
   private readonly ICakeFactory _cakeFactory;
   public Bakery(ICakeFactory cakeFactory)
   {
       Contract.Requires(cakeFactory != null);
       cakeFactory = _cakeFactory;
   }

   bool BakeStuff()
   {
       var cake = _cakeFactory.CreateCake();
       cake.NameOfCake = "StackOverflow";
       return cake.IsDecorated && cake.IsPacked;
   }
}
```

**Edit, Re Raise change Events**

This involves implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public interface ICake : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Which you can then raise on your mutable properties, e.g.

```
public string NameOfCake
{
    get { return _nameOfCake} ;
    set { 
        var propChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propChanged != null && value != _nameOfCake)
        {
            propChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameOfCake"));
        }
        _nameOfCake = value;
    }
}
```

And subscribe like so

```
var cake = new ChocolateCake();
cake.PropertyChanged += (sender, eventArgs) 
     => Console.WriteLine("Property {0} has changed", eventArgs.PropertyName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!And another question if I want to subscribe to an event that properties was changed,how it make?

Comment: I've updated, although I guess technically it is a new question (will be difficult for others to find). Skype - sorry, no, I've got a day job :)  - just keep asking good questions like the one you've asked here, and others will assist.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    public abstract TCake CreateCake<TCake>() where TCake : AbstractCake, new();
    public abstract AbstractBox CreateBox();
}

...

var cake = str.GetFactory().CreateCake<ChocolateCake>();
```